# How can I test WebServiceException handling using ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, servicestack, moq

I have a controller method something like:

```
public class FooController : Controller {

    private IApi api;

    public FooController(IApi api) { 
        this.api = api;
    }

    public ActionResult Index() {
        try {
            var data = api.GetSomeData();
            return(View(data));
        } catch(WebServiceException wsx) {
            if(wsx.StatusCode == 409) return(View("Conflict", wsx));
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The API instance is a wrapper around a ServiceStack JsonClient, and I've got methods on my ServiceStack service that will throw 409 conflicts like:

```
throw HttpError.Conflict(StatusMessages.USERNAME_NOT_AVAILABLE);
```

In my unit testing, I'm using Moq to mock the IApi, but I cannot work out how to 'simulate' the WebServiceException that's thrown by the JsonClient when the remote server returns a 409. My unit test code looks like this:

```
var mockApi = new Mock<IApi>();
var ex = HttpError.Conflict(StatusMessages.USERNAME_NOT_AVAILABLE);
var wsx = new WebServiceException(ex.Message, ex);
wsx.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict;
wsx.StatusDescription = ex.Message;

mockApi.Setup(api => api.GetSomeData()).Throws(wsx);

var c = new FooController(mockApi.Object);
var result = c.Index() as ViewResult;
result.ShouldNotBe(null);
result.ViewName.ShouldBe("Conflict");
```

However, there's a couple of fields - `ErrorMessage`, `ErrorCode`, `ResponseStatus` - that are read-only and so can't be set in my unit test.

How can I get ServiceStack to throw the same WebServiceException within a unit test that's being thrown when the client receives an HTTP error response from a server?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Client/WebServiceException.cs) for  `WebServiceException`, it seems that `ErrorMessage`, `ErrorCode`, and `ResponseStatus` are extracted from `ResponseDto`, which is publically settable.

And it looks like there is a  `CreateResponseStatus(string errorCode, string errorMessage, IEnumerable<ValidationErrorField> validationErrors)` method [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Client/ResponseStatusUtils.cs) which will help creating this?